# Visas How to get a Russia visa

Tags: visas, money, ireland, scams

I have been talking to a chick that says she needs 4500 euro in her bank account in order to obtain a 90 day tourist visa to visit Ireland.

Comment: While it is true that she would need to be able to show sufficient funds to support herself in Ireland to receive a visa, I'm sorry to say this has all the hallmarks of a scam.

Comment: There are two options. First, it could be a scam. Second, that "chick" as you call her misunderstands the requirements for a visa and the reasons for a refusal. She would need *a stable pattern of income and expenditures* to demonstrate a stable job and a reason to return to Russia after the visa runs out. Either way, don't send the money.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not give this person a penny, and do not continue talking to her!**

No country in the world requires that much for tourism, so she's 100% trying to trick you out of your money. No honest person would ever do that.

So block her on all social media and block her phone number, without a single word for an explanation.